# Using Splunk DB Connect 3 in a large environment with connection pool

Tags: sql-server, splunk

I am wondering if anyone can speak from experience with using DB Connect for a large number of sql server instances, each of which installed (so about 2,000 separate instances total). We currently use this to track the ms sql error log, perfmon, etc.

We are hoping to use DB Connect 3 to poll information from a few of the dynamic management views for stuff like suspect pages, memory dumps, IO, etc. For our monitoring purposes, it would be great if we can do this using DB Connect instead of other solutions requiring a job to create a new log based off of these sql tables.

My question is how the connection pool support is/what it can handle. Looking at the conf file I see that there is the option to use a connection pool (useConnectionPool) and you can set maxTotalConn , which I think in our case would be the number of instances we have (2,000 as I mentioned before).

Can this be done at all? Is it reliable with these many instances? If so, how have you implemented it? Our concern is that it wouldn't be able to handle this many connections for the connection pool, and would result in a huge performance problem. Opening up individual connections for each instance every time is not an option.

Interested in any input on this, thank you.